# Referring to theorems as its name (if there is one) or by its numbering

Tags: formatting, hyperref, cross-referencing, conditionals, theorems

I'll try to be specific. What I have is this:

[image]

*In the picture should say "(...) and what I need is to be able to (...)"

Even though I've explained what I need in the picture, the perfect answer to this question would be a way (using conditionals for \nameref maybe) to let the command \teo decide which case is: with theorem's name or without it. Some of my code is this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

% Commands
\newcommand{\teo}[1]{{\bfseries\upshape{\hyperref[#1]{\nameref{#1} (Teorema \ref{#1})}}}}

% Environment I've used
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\newcounter{theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{theorem}
    \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{#1}


    \tcbset{enhanced, breakable, colbacktitle = gray!50, coltitle = black, fonttitle = \bfseries, 
    attach boxed title to top left = {yshift = -\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift = 0.55cm}, 
    boxed title style = {rounded corners, colframe = gray!50, boxsep = 4pt},
    top = \tcboxedtitleheight/2+2mm,
    opacityframe = 0, opacityback = 0,
    borderline horizontal = {0.5mm}{0pt}{gray!50}}

    \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {\tcbset{title = Teorema \thetheorem}}%
        {\tcbset{title = #1 (Teorema \thetheorem)}}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[]\relax}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Theorem's Name] \label{t1}
    some text
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem} \label{t2}
    This theorem has no name.
\end{theorem}
If I refer with \verb=\teo{t1}=, \teo{t1}, it calls the all theorem (with its name and number) and want I want is to be able to call \teo{t2} with the same command (\verb=\teo{t2}=) but without the extra-space and the parenthesis.

\end{document}
```

I hope that I've explained myself. Thanks.

Comment: You should move `\begin{document}` after the last `\makeatother` (end of preamble material).

Comment: Yes, my bad (oops). Thanks you!

Comment: `\refstepcounter` should go before the redefinition of `\@currentlabel` and `\@currentlabelname`.

Comment: If I try, the reference produced by `\teo{t1}` becomes **Theorem's Name (Teorema Theorem's Name)**, which looks bizarre. I guess you want **Theorem's name (Teorema 2.7)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go on a deeper level; the name is stored in the third braced group resulting from the expansion of `\r@<label>`.

We can check whether this is empty and act consequently.

I used `\nameref*` and `\ref*` not to create several links but only the one generated by `\hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

% Packages I use
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{theorem}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    \tcbset{enhanced, breakable, colbacktitle = gray!50, coltitle = black, fonttitle = \bfseries, 
    attach boxed title to top left = {yshift = -\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift = 0.55cm}, 
    boxed title style = {rounded corners, colframe = gray!50, boxsep = 4pt},
    top = \tcboxedtitleheight/2+2mm,
    opacityframe = 0, opacityback = 0,
    borderline horizontal = {0.5mm}{0pt}{gray!50}}
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {\tcbset{title = Teorema \thetheorem}}%
        {\tcbset{title = #1 (Teorema \thetheorem)}}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]\relax}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\teo}[1]{{%
  \normalfont\bfseries\upshape
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{%
    % ref not yet defined
    Teorema \ref{#1}%
  }{%
    \protected@edef\@tempa{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname}%
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty
      % no name
      \hyperref[#1]{Teorema~\ref*{#1}}%
    \else
      % theorem has name
      \hyperref[#1]{\nameref*{#1} (Teorema~\ref*{#1})}%
    \fi
  }%
}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Theorem's Name] \label{t1}
    some text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} \label{t2}
    This theorem has no name.
\end{theorem}

If I refer with \verb=\teo{t1}=, \teo{t1}, 
it calls the all theorem (with its name and number) 
and want I want is to be able to call \teo{t2} with 
the same command (\verb=\teo{t2}=) but without the 
extra-space and the parenthesis.

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### A better implementation

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book}

% Packages I use
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{theorem}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theorem}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{theorem}%
    \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    \tcbset{enhanced, breakable, colbacktitle = gray!50, coltitle = black, fonttitle = \bfseries, 
    attach boxed title to top left = {yshift = -\tcboxedtitleheight/2, xshift = 0.55cm}, 
    boxed title style = {rounded corners, colframe = gray!50, boxsep = 4pt},
    top = \tcboxedtitleheight/2+2mm,
    opacityframe = 0, opacityback = 0,
    borderline horizontal = {0.5mm}{0pt}{gray!50}}
    \ifstrempty{#1}%
        {\tcbset{title = Teorema \thetheorem}}%
        {\tcbset{title = #1 (Teorema \thetheorem)}}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[]\relax}{%
    \end{tcolorbox}
}
\makeatother

% Commands

\NewDocumentCommand{\teoformat}{m}{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\teo}{m}
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { r@#1 }
   {% the reference is defined
    \peluche_teo:cn { r@#1 } { #1 }
   }
   {% the reference is not yet defined
    \teoformat{Teorema\nobreakspace\ref{#1}}%
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \peluche_teo:Nn
 {% the reference is defined
  \exp_args:Ne \tl_if_empty:nTF { \tl_item:Nn #1 { 3 } }
   {% no name
    \hyperref[#2]{\teoformat{Teorema\nobreakspace\ref*{#2}}}
   }
   {% name exists
    \hyperref[#2]{\teoformat{\nameref*{#2}~(Teorema\nobreakspace\ref*{#2})}}
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \peluche_teo:Nn { c }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Theorem's Name] \label{t1}
    some text
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem} \label{t2}
    This theorem has no name.
\end{theorem}

If I refer with \verb=\teo{t1}=, \teo{t1}, 
it calls the all theorem (with its name and number) 
and want I want is to be able to call \teo{t2} with 
the same command (\verb=\teo{t2}=) but without the 
extra-space and the parenthesis.

\end{document}
```

The idea is the same as before, but it's easier to extract the third item from `\r@<label>` which behaves like a token list variable in order to robustly test whether it's empty or not and take the appropriate action.

I introduced `\teoformat` so it's easier to change the format of the reference without polluting the code with many formatting instructions.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you! Also, may I ask you why do you use this? \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@thirdoffive\csname r@#1\endcsname}%

What is that for? Can you tell me where you learned that?

Comment: @Peluche Wait for a better implementation.